# How to remove extra text from url in python

Tags: python, pandas

I have more than 1000 rows of url something like this inside the dataframe

**I have df['profile'] column in my dataframe**

```
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/797804071063343105/KPytXWtY_normal.jpg
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/903374198009188353/pDuYl5Uk_normal.jpg
http://pbs.twimg.com/profile_images/1101088756432396290/5bzisDRx_normal.png
```

I need to remove only **_normal** from the images url in python

I have tried with this but it is not working

```
df.profile.str.replace(r'_normal', r'')
```

**When i applied this line i got the profile images in the row. Rather than i want to replace the new values with the previous one**

Comment: `df['profile'] = df.profile.str.replace(r'_normal', r'')`

Comment: @piRSquared how to repalce the new values in the df['profile'] with the previous one

Comment: @piRSquared when I applied this line i got an extra row of profile rather replacing the previous values with the new one

Comment: @TayyabGulsherVohra new row? you meant column right? Anyway, it should work, review for any typos.